# Is there any way to run one file and fire multiple magento2 command in Ubuntu?

Tags: magento2, script, shell

Is there any way to run one file and fire multiple magento2 command like
Index, static content, deploy, cache clear etc. And for all files permissions set Automatically.

Comment: May be you are looking for [Script file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223691/how-do-i-create-a-script-file-for-terminal-commands)

Comment: Yes That what i am looking for @NeroPhung

Comment: Nice, hope it help you @Jaimin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a Linux system, then you can create commands.sh file and put all this code.

```
rm -rf var/cache/ var/page_cache/ var/view_preprocessed/ pub/static/frontend/ pub/static/adminhtml/
php -dmemory_limit=8G bin/magento cache:clean
php -dmemory_limit=8G bin/magento cache:flush
php -dmemory_limit=8G bin/magento catalog:images:resize
php -dmemory_limit=8G bin/magento setup:upgrade
php -dmemory_limit=8G bin/magento setup:di:compile
php -dmemory_limit=8G bin/magento indexer:reset
php -dmemory_limit=8G bin/magento indexer:reindex
php -dmemory_limit=8G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
chmod 777 ./app/etc
chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml
```

Comment: i wonder if someone already copied this an run on his setup...

Comment: I run some of the above commands on my local system. you can suggest your review if I wrote the wrong answer.